# How can I use doctrine embeddable with json column?

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

In my Symfony project, I have a doctrine entity that contains a nested object. Like in the example below:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\EntityRepository")
 */
class Enity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     *
     * @var int
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     *
     * @var NestedObject
     */
    private $nestedObject;

    public function getNestedObject(): NestedObject
    {
        return $this->nestedObject;
    }

    public function setNestedObject(NestedObject $object): void
    {
        $this->nestedObject = $object;
    }
}
```

and nested object:

```
class NestedObject
{
    /**
     * @var FirstOption
     */
    private $firstOption;

    /**
     * @var SecondOption
     */
    private $secondOption;

    /**
     * @return FirstOption
     */
    public function getFirstOption(): FirstOption
    {
        return $this->firstOption;
    }

    /**
     * @return SecondOption
     */
    public function getSecondOption(): SecondOption
    {
        return $this->secondOption;
    }
}
```

I want to store the Nested Object in Postgres as jsonb, in such a way that the object is automatically serialized when saved and deserialized when fetched from the database.
I have read doctrine documentation and didn't find something about json and embeddable objects.

Is there any way to store embeddable objects as json structure without creating an extra column for any property? Or any alternative for convenient work with nested json objects?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately serializng in json is not that easy in php, you can implement `\JsonSerializable` interface but it only works for `json_encode`, if you'd want to deserialize the object in a getter you would need to create the object yourself:

```
public function getNestedObject(): NestedObject
{
    $json = $this->nestedObject;
    $nestedObject = new NestedObject();
    $nestedObject->setX($json['x']);
    ... // rest of setters
    return $nestedObject;
}
```

It will be much easier and probably better to create relation to nested object, or use serialize interface if JSON is not necessary. If json is necessary the above aproach is probably the best way out.